# Why does this getter method has been called several times in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, getter, es6-class

I have a Store which will be provided to the component. In this Store file, there are several getter function. But I find only this getter function will be executed three times since `this.rawMonthlyImpacts` will be only changed once when the api get response from backend. I am so confused because other getter function in this file will be only executed once. During every execution, `this.rawMonthlyImpacts` is always same. Because this function is time-consuming, so I want to figure out why this happens. Hope you can give me some advice. Thanks!

```
get Impacts(){
        const monthlyImpacts = new Map<string, Map<string, number>>();
        if (this.rawMonthlyImpacts) {
            this.rawMonthlyImpacts.forEach((impact) => {
                if (impact.Impact > 0) {
                    const month = TimeConversion.fromTimestampToMonthString(impact.Month);
                    const tenantId = impact.TenantId;
                    const tenantImpact = impact.Impact;

                    if (!monthlyImpacts.has(month)) {
                        const tenantList = new Map<string, number>();
                        monthlyImpacts.set(month, tenantList.set(tenantId, tenantImpact));
                    } else {
                        const tenantWithImpactMap = monthlyImpacts.get(month);
                        if (!tenantWithImpactMap.has(tenantId)) {
                            tenantWithImpactMap.set(tenantId, tenantImpact);
                        } else {
                            tenantWithImpactMap.set(tenantId, tenantWithImpactMap.get(tenantId) + tenantImpact);
                        }
                        monthlyImpacts.set(month, tenantWithImpactMap);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return monthlyImpacts;
    },
```

Update: I have find that there are other two functions use `this.Impacts`. If I remove these two functions, the getter function will only be executed only once. I think the getter function uses the cache to store data, so once the data is calculated for the first time, subsequent calls to the getter function should not be re-executed, only the value in the cache needs to be retrieved. So I am very confused about why this getter function will be executed 3 times.

```
getImpactedTenants(month: string): string[] {
    return Array.from(this.Impacts.get(month).keys());
},
get overallMonthlyImpactedTenants(): Map<string, number> {
    return new Map<string, number>(
        Array.from(this.Impacts)?.map((monthEntries) => {
            const month = monthEntries[0];
            const impactedTenants = monthEntries[1].size;
            return [month, impactedTenants];
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's called multiple times? Where is `Impact` accessed?

Comment: It was accessed by other getter function. I add a console.log function in ```Impact```  and the log was executed three times. If the variable dependent on the getter function has not changed, will the function be re-executed every time the getter is called? But when I call the function by ```Store.Impact``` in the component, it will not cause the console.log function happen. So I think if the variable dependent on the getter function has not changed, the function won't be re-executed every time the getter is called.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly is happening without more context, but remember that with a get function, every single time you reference that property (.Impacts in this case) the get function will be called.

Assuming that each impact stored in this.rawMonthlyImpacts which you loop through is an instance of the class with this getter, then as far as I'm aware, you are calling the get function each time you reference impact.Impacts, such as in the conditional:

```
if (impact.Impact > 0) {
```

I might be way off though; I'm unfamiliar with React and so my answer is based only on my experience with vanilla JS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I checked again and updated the details of the problem. Hope you can give me more help, thanks!

Comment: Without more context I can't really offer any extra advice unfortunately. If I could see the code for the entire Class (rather than just the methods you posted) I might be able to see what's happening. If rawMonthlyImpacts also has get/set functions then they will also be called each time you reference this.rawMonthlyImpacts or assign a new value to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I find the reason, I will update this question.